# SQL - Conditional LIKE expression based on query parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, select, conditional-statements, sql-like

I want to select rows using LIKE %:myParam% based on the query parameter ONLY if it is not null or empty. 
If the query parameter is null or empty, I want to select all records & drop the Like %%. 
How can I do that? I have tried with case-when but I am not sure How to use Like in it. Basically I want to use the like based on null check's result.

I have something like this:

```
Select * from myTable tbl
WHERE tbl.myCol LIKE '%' || :myParam|| '%'
```

For example: 
Select * from myTable returns 10 rows - from which 4 rows have myCol= null,
I want to select 10 rows if :myParam is null/empty otherwise I want to get rows matching the LIKE expression. I dont want to get 6 rows if null is passed as :myParam

Comment: `tbl.myCol LIKE '%' || nvl(:myParam,tbl.myCol) || '%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query should work. Just check if you are passing space(s) in :myParam.

```
Select * from myTable tbl
WHERE tbl.myCol LIKE '%' || :myParam|| '%'
```

For example if I run the following query it returns me the list of all tables.

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name like '%' || '' || '%'
```

And the following query returns the list of all tables containing the word TEMP.

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name like '%' || trim('TEMP') || '%'
```

You can try putting a trim around your myParam.

```
Select * from myTable tbl
WHERE tbl.myCol LIKE '%' || trim(:myParam) || '%'
```

Try this query for including rows where your column contains NULL values.

```
SELECT * from myTable tbl
WHERE (tbl.myCol LIKE '%' || :myParam|| '%' 
OR (TRIM(:myParam) IS NULL AND tbl.myCol IS NULL))
```

Comment: The above queries exclude the rows which have null in myCol when null is supplied as a parameter. I want to select all rows if :myParam=null, else if :myParam is not null then I want to select rows based on LIKE epression.

Comment: @zeppelin This answer looks correct to me, perhaps there is a problem with your query/data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please read my comments on your answer. I have added an example there to explain it better.

Comment: @zeppelin Added one more query in my original answer.

Comment: @zeppelin If his last query suddenly starts working, then it means you had whitespace in your `:myParam` parameter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen His last query worked. Thanks. However I can confirm, there were no nulls. Because I was supplying the :myParam value through Sql Developer's IDE and NOT manually. There is a NULL checkbox before  we run the query in SqlDeveloper & I used that to supply :myParam.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the expression `LIKE '%%'` will return all records (at least it does in MySQL), so you can use `COALESCE()` to change a `NULL` value into empty string:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable tbl
WHERE tbl.myCol LIKE '%' || COALESECE(:myParam, '') || '%'
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it avoids a messy `CASE` expression, or something possibly worse than that.

Comment: Using the above query filters the null items also and returns only non-null column rows. I want to get null rows also if :myParam is null/empty else I want to filter based on :myParam.

Comment: For example: Select * from myTable  returns 10 rows - from which 4 rows have myCol= null - I want to select 10 rows if myParam is null/empty otherwise I want to get rows matching the LIKE. Using your query returns 6 rows if I pass null in :myParam.

Comment: I think you have something else inside your `:myParam`.  My query should be working for you AFAIK.

Comment: I am not getting the rows which have null in myCol if I supply :myParam=null . I have rechecked it & still getting only non-null myCol rows. I am using Oracle Database